# write onty keyword equals and not repeat

Tags: javascript

i have this code, i need this same code in javascript native

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
      
     var pulsado = false;

     $("input").keydown(function(){
       if(pulsado) return false;
       pulsado = true;
        })
         
      .keyup(function(){
       pulsado = false;
      });
    });
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    manten una tecla pulsada <input type="text" >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following solution.

```js
window.onload = function() {

  var pulsado = false,
    input = document.getElementById('input');

  input.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    if (pulsado) e.preventDefault();
    pulsado = true;
  });

  input.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
    pulsado = false;
  });

}
```

```html
manten una tecla pulsada <input type="text" id='input'>
```

Comment: If you type a key it should not be repeated, example: when typed `a` for a time 5 seg should write only `a` , and not `aaaaaaaaaaaa`

Comment: test my snnipet please pressing the same key

Comment: @hubman Check it.

Comment: good !!!only a ask please, It is not necessary to use the key press event?

Comment: @hubman In your case using `keypress` wouldn't do the job. You need `keyup` and `keydown` events.